# JFXtra agenda to only show between certain times?

Tags: java, javafx, jfxtras

For example if I only want it to show ranges from 9am to 9pm? displayedCalendar property doesn't seem to change anything, only changed the displayed date.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now there is only a week and day skin, showing both 24 hours. So the answer is: not at the moment.

Comment: That said, maybe a little research into if the viewport of a scrollpane can be manipulated to only allow a specific area would be the easiest way to get the required behavior.

Comment: Sorry, might be a silly question but how do I access the scrollpane of the agenda?

Comment: You don't, it's embedded, so it's something that needs to be coded in. It was just a brain flash I had. But that does not mean you can't do a little reseach; any scrollpane can be tested to see if limiting the range of the viewport is possible. I would do it, but right now I'm working on a gauge and want to that first (if the issue is a feature, like this, bugs go first).